# Books about electromagnetism/electrodynamics using the language of differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, physics

I’m staring to learn electromagnetism and electrodynamics and I’m not very satisfactory with the language and concepts of traditional vector analysis. I’ve heard about the modern formulation of the theory in the language of differential forms. Can anyone give me some references (books, papers, etc.) on this?